# No se ejecutan los eventos asignados a los elementos en el DOM cuando los traigo con ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy desarrollando un sistema y tengo esta vista de cards que empeze a cargar con ajax.

Cuando lo hacia desde el archivo .php los eventos que asignaba los iconos funcionaban bien y hacian lo que se esperaba, pero cuando empeze a poner ajax ya no se ejecutan.

Alguien que le hallá pasado algo similar que me pueda ayudar?
Gracias por su tiempo.

Este es el codigo que uso para llamar el ajax

```
// LOAD CARDS
function loadCards() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/rentalsTable.php",
    success: function (res) {
      if (res) {
        $("#containerH").html(res);
      }
    },
  });
}
loadCards();
```

No estoy usando datatables, lo estoy cargando asi:

```
<?php require_once '../models/roomsModel.php';

$rooms =  RoomsModel::getAll();
$cards = '';
foreach ($rooms as $habitacion) {
  if ($habitacion["estado"] == "Limpieza") {
    $cards .= '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 habitacion-item habitacion-tipo-item habitacion-view-item" category="' . $habitacion["estado"] . '" tipo="' . $habitacion["tipo"] . '" vista="' . $habitacion["vista"] . '"><div class="card background-info"><div class="card-header"><h4 class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between" style=" width:100%"><i class="fas fa-info-circle font-20 info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoHabitación" idHabitacion="' . $habitacion["idhabitacion"] . '"></i><span>' . $habitacion["codigo"] . '</span><i class="fa fa-spinner font-20 limpieza" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#limpieza" idHabitacion="' . $habitacion["idhabitacion"] . '" ></i></h4></div><div class="card-body habitacion-card d-flex flex-column justify-content-between"><p class="text-white">' . $habitacion["descripcion"] . '</p><p class="center"><i class="fas fa-bed"></i></p></div></div></div>';
  } else if ($habitacion["estado"] == "Libre") {
    $cards .= '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 habitacion-item habitacion-tipo-item habitacion-view-item" category="' . $habitacion["estado"] . '" tipo="' . $habitacion["tipo"] . '" vista="' . $habitacion["vista"] . '"><div class="card background-success text-white"><div class="card-header"><h4 class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between idroom" style="width:100%"><i class="fas fa-info-circle font-20 info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoHabitación" idHabitacion="' . $habitacion["idhabitacion"] . '"></i><span>' . $habitacion["codigo"] . '</span><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right font-20 idroom" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registrar" idroom=' . $habitacion["idhabitacion"] . ' precio=' . $habitacion["precio"] . ' coderoom=' . $habitacion["codigo"] . '"></i></h4></div><div class="card-body habitacion-card d-flex flex-column justify-content-between"><p class="text-white">' . $habitacion["descripcion"] . '</p><p class="m-0 center"><i class="fas fa-bed"></i></p></div></div></div>';
  } else if ($habitacion["estado"] == "Reservada") {
    $cards .= '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 habitacion-item habitacion-tipo-item habitacion-view-item" category="' . $habitacion["estado"] . '" tipo="' . $habitacion["tipo"] . '" vista="' . $habitacion["vista"] . '"><div class="card background-warning text-white"><div class="card-header"><h4 class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between" style="width:100%"><i class="fas fa-info-circle font-20 info"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoHabitación" idHabitacion="' . $habitacion["idhabitacion"] . '"></i><span>' . $habitacion["codigo"] . '</span><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right font-20" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alquiler"></i></h4></div><div class="card-body habitacion-card d-flex flex-column justify-content-between"><p class="text-white">' . $habitacion["descripcion"] . '</p><p class="center"><i class="fas fa-bed"></i></p></div></div></div>';
  } else {
    $cards .= '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 habitacion-item habitacion-tipo-item habitacion-view-item" category="' . $habitacion["estado"] . '" tipo="' . $habitacion["tipo"] . '" vista="' . $habitacion["vista"] . '"><div class="card card background-danger text-white"><div class="card-header"><h4 class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between" style=" width:100%"><i class="fas fa-info-circle font-20 info" idHabitacion="' . $habitacion["idhabitacion"] . '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoHabitación"></i><span>' . $habitacion["codigo"] . '</span><i class="fas fa-plus-circle font-20 recargo" recargo="' . $habitacion["idhabitacion"] . '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pedido"></i></h4></div><div class="card-body habitacion-card d-flex flex-column justify-content-between"><p class="text-white">' . $habitacion["descripcion"] . '</p><span class="text-white text-center">' . $habitacion["cliente"] . '</span></div></div></div>';
  }
}

echo $cards;
```

Comment: Hola, quita el if (res) y solo deja y pon $("#containerH").append(res);

Comment: Jorge no paso nada, sigue sin ejecutar

Comment: Entonces tienes un error y el ajax regresa un error prueba poniente error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) para ver que te sale. aqui tienes un ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918248/ajax-success-and-error-function-failure/17549074

Comment: voy a hacerlo, pero al tener un error no me deberia cargar los elementos?

Comment: No paso nada, me sigue cargando todo normal pero sin los eventos

Comment: Hola elar, lo que pasa es que estas utilizando mal la funcion `$.ajax`, ya que estas haciendo una solicitud tipo post y no estas mandando ningun dato, te sugiero quitar lo que seria el `type: POST`, y ver que arroja

Comment: si nos puedes compartir parte de tu codigo legible del html o js estaria bien, verificar que estas inciando la funcion correctamente o de que forma la estas ejecutando

Comment: tambien siempre puedes utilizar el [.load](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Hablas de *eventos*, pero no veo que asignes ningún *evento*. A lo sumo, estarías intentando agregar elementos. Aclarado eso, ¿cuál es el problema, que los **elementos** no se crean? Recomiendo que depures tu código poniendo un  `console.log(res);` y revisando lo que aparece en consola. Confírmanos también que tienes un elemento con `id="containerH"`